# Typecasting before division (or any other mathematical operator) of columns in dataframes

Tags: python, type-conversion, dataframe, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `A`, `B`. I need to add a column `C` which is basically the division of entries in `A` by the entries in `B`.

I tried this:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] / df['B']
```

But I need to convert to double or float before I do this. How should I type-cast the `dtype` of the columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
df['C'] = df['A'] * 1.0 / df['B']
```

Comment: `float(df['A'])` would more explicit.

Comment: `float(df["A"])` certainly reads better, but won't work unless `df["A"]` only has one value.  Either multiply by `1.0` as in the original method, or use `df["A"].astype(float)`.

Comment: The accepted answer in its current form won't work.  `df = DataFrame({"A": [1,2], "B": [2,3]}); float(df["A"])/df["B"]` will produce `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

Comment: @DSM good catch. Then I choose `* 1.0`, since it seems duck friendly and is common to many programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

Or this:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].astype('float') / df['B']
```